# File gets content

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, file-get-contents

I work for a voluntary fire brigade and years ago I created an operational status code using `file_get_contents`. Now it has no function anymore and I have no idea how to fix it.

```
<?php
$word = array ('T1','T2','T3','B1','B2','B3','B4','S1','S2','S3');
$word2 = array ('keine Einsätze');
$quelltext = file_get_contents("https://www.feuerwehr-huettendorf.at/einsatz.html");

foreach ($word as $einsatz) {
  $pos = strpos($quelltext, $einsatz);

  if($pos !== FALSE)
  {
    echo '<img title="Feuerwehr im Einsatz" alt="Feuerwehr im Einsatz" width="160" height="50" src="/images/content/icons/einsatz.gif" />';}

  }
    
  foreach ($word2 as $bereit) {
     $pos2 = strpos($quelltext, $bereit);

     if($pos2 !== FALSE)
     {
       echo '<img title="Einsatzbereit" alt="Einsatzbereit" width="160" height="50" src="/images/content/icons/einsatzbereit.gif" />';}
     }
?>
```

Comment: Just stating "it doesnt work" does not narrow down your problem at all. How does it *"... has no function ... "*? Explain what it should do and what it does instead. Any error message would also help.

Comment: Agreed. It's hard for us to guess exactly what the problem is. Please describe precisely what occurs when you try to run this code (and precisely what you expected to occur instead).

Comment: Hi, the problem, this code doesnt work anymore.

Comment: The code should read the words in use (Im Einsatz) or ready for use (Einsatzbereit) on this side https://www.feuerwehr-huettendorf.at/einsatz.html and then display a specific graphic on the status.

Comment: By the way though, there is nothing in your code which searches for either `Im Einsatz` or `Einsatzbereit`. The code looks for any of the items in the `$word` and `$word2` arrays, neither of which contain the words you've mentioned.

Comment: Does the call to `file_get_contents()` return any data or not? Is the problem in retrieving the information, or in parsing it? Has the format of the site changed, so the words you are looking for are just not there?

Comment: P.S. For future reference "doesnt work anymore" is not a useful description of any problem. Can you fix a fire engine which "doesn't work anymore", or would you need a bit more info? You told us what it's supposed to do, but not what it's currently doing instead. (Luckily I could guess - see below - but it's not always that simple. Often you'd need to specify exact error messages or other symptoms and behaviour)

Answer (score 0):

The source code of that URL you've mentioned is (at the time of writing) simply this:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" style="height: 300px; width: 100%; frameborder: 0px" width="100%" height="680" src="https://www.feuerwehr-krems.at/Dokumente/Bezirk/Die%20Feuerwehren/Die%20Feuerwehren/FFInfo_Allgemein.asp?EldisID=222201&amp;Select=1" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

It doesn't contain any of the content your code is looking for. I wonder if someone changed the way the server-side application is set up.

You need to directly get the source code of the URL mentioned in that iframe instead, e.g.

```
$quelltext = file_get_contents("https://www.feuerwehr-krems.at/Dokumente/Bezirk/Die%20Feuerwehren/Die%20Feuerwehren/FFInfo_Allgemein.asp?EldisID=222201&Select=1");
```

This contains the real contents of the page.